# Creating a Live USB for Crunchbang

Tags: live-usb, crunchbang

I am looking to run one of my computers on Crunchbang Linux, but I cannot seem to be able to find a way to create a live USB of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating LiveUSB of every .iso image works in the same way.

You may find this link useful:

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

Comment: I have already tried to use the second link you gave me, but it created an Oracle VM thingy, which my computer cannot support...

Comment: How a simple tool that writes ISO image to the disk could have created an 'Oracle VM'? Download the iso image of #! and use one of the many tools available to put it onto the USB stick.

Answer (score 3):

Get **UNetbootin** from your package manager/software-center if you're already running Linux:

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install unetbootin` for Debian and other Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu. 
    *- drop "sudo" if you are running as root.*
2. Type `unetbootin` in the terminal to launch.
3. You can then use the second option to find and load onto the usb your downloaded .iso of CrunchBang etc.

Works for most distros. I believe it doesn't work for Arch.